# Flow react native import image error cannot resolve module RelativeImageStub

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I'm quite new to flow, I'm getting a flow error importing an image in react-native:

```
import EditIcon from '../../../../../assets/images/edit-icon.png';

<Image
   style={imageStyle}
   source={EditIcon}
/>
```

I get this error:

> "cannot resolve module RelativeImageStub"

This is my flowconfig where I have the RelativeImageStub

```
module.name_mapper='^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)$' -> 'RelativeImageStub'
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Hi @Graeme, what OS are you working on? ie where this issue happened?

Comment: Seems to only have happened on a windows machine for us, not mac or linux.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of matching the whole module name, you can use extension matcher.

Change:

```
module.name_mapper='^[./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)$' -> 'RelativeImageStub'
```

To:

```
module.name_mapper.extension='\(bmp\|gif\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\|psd\|svg\|webp\|m4v\|mov\|mp4\|mpeg\|mpg\|webm\|aac\|aiff\|caf\|m4a\|mp3\|wav\|html\|pdf\)' -> 'RelativeImageStub'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is no flow definition file.

A work-around to remove the error is to [create a stub](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/wiki/CLI-Commands-and-Flags#create-stub).

With `flow-typed` installed (e.g. `npm i -g flow-typed`), execute the following in your project's root directory:

`flow-typed create-stub RelativeImageStub@x.x.x`